# VF Page to Override the Lead Conversion Edit Page

Tags: visualforce

I cannot build VF pages so I'm hoping someone can help me...

When you convert a Lead, you have a page in Edit mode that has the conversion information and then a spot to enter tasks. I'd like to remove the reference to the tasks but there is no layout that I can edit. I need a VF page that has the same Lead conversion information but no task details. We don't use standard tasks and activities so don't want people tempted to fill these out.

Has someone done this? Is there a place I could grab a page and modify it? I can't build one from scratch but I know enough to possibly modify the code from an existing page.

Thanks,
Heidi

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try installing [Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU) by Clerisoft from the App Exchange (free) to see if you can convert the page to standard VisualForce and edit it to remove the Activities sections. Overall, I've had pretty good success at converting standard pages using their utility.

As long as you can locate the standard page you want to convert to VF, you've at least got a chance of success. It doesn't always convert successfully, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I can't actually find the page anywhere, that is part of the issue. A friend told me it could be done with a VF page... which I'm not even sure I would know how to override with. You can't edit it and I'm not sure how to access it either. :( I will look up that app though, thanks!